# How to NDSolve system with motion integral?

Tags: differential-equations

I deal with set of ODE, which looks like

```
f'[i][t] = c + Sum[G[f[j][t]-f[i][t]], {j, 1, N}]
```

where `G[t]` is smooth differentiable non-linear function (for simplicity consider `G=Sin[t]`) and `N` is the number of equations. The quantity `c` is the constant. I know that this system have motion integrals.

I can compute the value of motion integral `J` at `t=0` from initial conditions (they are known). For instance, I obtain `J[t=0]=I0`. Then J use `NDSolve` and find out solutions of my set of ODEs on the interval `[0,T]`. Next, I would like to compute `J[t=t0]`, where `t0` in `[0,T]`. Surprsingly, `J[t=t0] != J[t=0]`. That is impossible because `J` is the motion integral!

I have performed some research and find that not all integration schemes are appropriate for systems with motion integrals.

Does anyone can guide me how can I should use `NDSolve` for systems with motion integrals?

Comment: See https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveProjection.html, also https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveSPRK.html

Comment: `I` stands for $i$. In general avoid using uppercase letters for symbols.

Comment: @I.M. , as I understand with `"Projection"` method I should explicitly write motion integral, isn't it?

Comment: Right, not sure if invariant should be necessarily explicit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of the projection method (invariant is implicit, i.e. it can be an integral to be evaluated for given q and p) with implicit RK (with this coefficients method is also symplectic):

```
H = 1/2*p[t]^2 + 1/2*q[t]^2+1/3*q[t]^3 ;

W[q_?NumericQ, p_?NumericQ] := 1/2*p^2 + 1/2*q^2+1/3*q^3  ;

{Q, P}= NDSolveValue[
{q'[t] ==  D[H, p[t]], p'[t] == -D[H, q[t]], q[0] == 0.45, p[0] == 0.0},
{q[t], p[t]},
{t, 0, 10},
Method -> {
"FixedStep",
Method -> {
"Projection",
"Invariants" -> {W[q[t], p[t]]},
Method -> {
"ImplicitRungeKutta",
"DifferenceOrder"->10,
"Coefficients" -> "ImplicitRungeKuttaGaussCoefficients",
"ImplicitSolver" -> {"Newton", AccuracyGoal -> MachinePrecision, PrecisionGoal -> MachinePrecision, "IterationSafetyFactor" -> 1}
}
}
},
MaxSteps -> Infinity,
StartingStepSize -> 0.01
]  ;
Table[W[Q, P], {t, 0.0, 10.0, 0.01}]  -  inv // Abs // Max
```